# Can the verb "to shadow" mean to make something else unnoticeable by drawing attention away?

Tags: meaning, expressions

I once saw the expression "to shadow" being used to say that something makes another thing unnoticeable because it attracts more attention, but I can't find a definition for this expression that fits this.
Example:

> Famous singers shadow other artists that try to make a living...

Does this sentence make sense?

Comment: "cast a shadow over" would probably work better, if you insist on using _shadow_. Please do [a little research](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shadow) before asking if a word is appropriate...

Comment: 'Eclipse' is the single-word metaphor. I've not found 'shadow' in a list of synonyms (and I didn't expect to).

Comment: **Shadow** is more usually used the other way round: in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/shadow) verb 2.2 Accompany (someone) in their daily activities at work in order to gain experience at or insight into a job.

Comment: @WeatherVane That's _exactly_ what I was thinking when I saw the Q.

Comment: Not usually, but as this is on a site primarily about computers and programming, **it IS used in many programming languages** to mean one variable/declaration 'hiding' or 'masking' another: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing .

Comment: @WeatherVane - the police in the UK might 'shadow' someone they suspect, that is, follow and watch them without revealing themselves.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The verb 'shadow' is not used in that way. You are probably thinking of **overshadow**, "to cause someone or something to seem less important or less happy".

> Famous singers overshadow other artists that try to make a living.
> Jane has always felt overshadowed by her famous elder sister.
> My happiness was overshadowed by the bad news.
> My mother's imprisonment overshadowed my childhood.
> My dog's death overshadowed my joy at Biden's victory.
> Cristiano Ronaldo came out fighting after the defeat to Barcelona in El Clasico. It was clear Lionel Messi had overshadowed him throughout.
> Crown Prince Mohammed bin Zayed overshadowed him as a leader.

[Overshadow (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/overshadow)

Comment: One problem: The verb can be transitive, or intransitive. Your passive voice examples indicate transitive. So isn't it possible...""Famous singers **over**shadow other artists that try to make a living..?

Comment: @Cascabel - fixed.

Comment: Oh My Dog...those sentences are very nice...+1

Comment: @Cascabel - my dog - tempting fate, maybe?